# Calling the Button from other form

Tags: c#, listview, refresh

Good day to all. i am facing another problem. i have 2 forms, 1 form is the main form where the listview(show my data from database), refresh button(refreshing listview) and add new item button ( where to add new item).
when i pressed add new item, another form showing.
so my problem is how can i refresh my listview when im done adding new item using the btn_Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) or how can i access the btn_Refresh_Click

```
private void btn_Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowItems("B.S. in Information Technology", 1, 18);
        ShowItems("B.S. in Entrepreneurial Management", 19, 36);
        ShowItems("B.S. in Industrial Engineering", 37, 54);
        ShowItems("B.S. in Electronics Engineering", 55, 72);
        ShowItems("Technical-Vocational Courses", 73, 90);
    }
```

ShowItems is a method for sql select statement to show the items to listview.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a public member function for refreshing:

```
public void Refresh()
{
    ShowItems("B.S. in Information Technology", 1, 18);
    ShowItems("B.S. in Entrepreneurial Management", 19, 36);
    ShowItems("B.S. in Industrial Engineering", 37, 54);
    ShowItems("B.S. in Electronics Engineering", 55, 72);
    ShowItems("Technical-Vocational Courses", 73, 90);
}
```

And call it from your button handler:

```
private void btn_Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Refresh();
}
```

And now you can also call it from anywhere else!

Answer (score 0):

You can either do something like this:

```
MyAddForm fmAdd = new MyAddForm();
fmAdd.ShowDialog();
btn_Refresh_Click(null,null);

OR

MyAddForm fmAdd = new MyAddForm();
fmAdd.ShowDialog();
RefreshData()
```

Take your logic out of the refresh button click and add it to a new method called RefreshData and make sure the button click calls RefreshData

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to create a new method change the access of btn_Refresh_Click event to public and call that using

```
btn_Refresh_Click(null,null);
```

and when you call this from other form use the object of form2 and call this event

Let f2 is the object of Form2

```
f2.btn_Refresh_Click(null,null);
```

If you want to be more good programmer try to use delegates